# 301 Redirect Subdirectory Path to Single Directory

Tags: redirect

As I am in the process of a site migration, I have been struggling with a 301 redirect issue, and would love some help.

I am going to move an entire domain (www.oldsite.com) to a new domain (www.newsite.com). I planned to accomplish this by changing the DNSto point to the new server. On the new site, I am trying to set up 301 redirects in my .htaccess file to provide a destination for any URLs that will not exist.

Most of the redirects are fine:
**Redirect 301 /old-dir-1/ /new-dir-1/**
... works fine.

However, if I want to also redirect a subdirectory:

**Redirect 301 /old-dir-1/subdir/ /new-dir-1/**

... the actual result is:
**www.newsite.com/new-dir-1/subdir**

I do not want to pass through the subdirectory.

I have tried a ton of combinations and tutorials and Rewrite Rules like:
**RewriteRule ^old-dir-1/(.*) /new-dir-1/$1 [R=301,L]**

And countless other variations... any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone comes across an issue like this, here is how I solved:

1) I made sure no application logic was conflicting with the redirects. In this particular case WordPress was also using a redirect plugin which needed to be disabled.

2) I revised the order of the lines in my 301 entries, placing the most specific URLs at the top, and the less specific below.

IE, first:
*Redirect 301 /old-dir-1/subdir/ /new-dir-1/*
and then...
*/old-dir-1/ /new-dir-1/*